# Is there a way to format a number to use comma but not limit the number of decimals?

Tags: vba, format

I am using this

```
Format(Evaluate(strg), "standard")
```

but it's not exactly what I want.

1. If there is not decimal needed I don't want to see ".00" tacked onto the end.
2. If the decimal can go out further than 2 digits I would like to see more accuracy than 2 digits. Not limited to 2.
3. I like all the commas for 1000's

Comment: `Format(Evaluate(strg), "#,##0.0#")` I believe.

Comment: That still gives unneeded decimal such as 9+6 = 15.0     Also it limits to only 2 decimals max. I want precision.

Comment: `--Format(Evaluate(strg), "#,##0.#########")`

Comment: That will work. Thank you